# Using Yahoo Pipes to makes tweets link to url they contain rather than Twitter

Tags: url, twitter, hyperlink, yahoo-pipes

I'm wondering how you can use Yahoo Pipes to get any tweets than contain a url to link to that url when clicked, instead of linking to Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some assumptions.

- You want the first URL if there are multiple links in the message
- If there is no URL, you will skip the tweet
- You only care about http and https links

The flow ends up:

- 1 *Fetch Feed* - Use twitter RSS
- 2 *Filter* - `item.description` Matches regex `https?://`
- 3 *Rename* - `item.description` Copy As `link`
- 4 *Regex* - In `item.link` replace `^.*?(https?://[\w:#@%/;$()~?+-=\.&]+).*$` with `$1` (s)

If you want to see all tweets, then the simplest thing is to split the feed at the top and filter the ones with and without URLs and only process the URL ones. Finally you can remerge the feeds before outputting.

If you want more url types, change the `https?://` to `(https?|ftp|etc)://` in step 2 and 4

I made a sample [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e791303aab6722d25e6fbbef0c9d7c27).

Comment: @Gavin Brock: Thanks very much indeed.  I have to say that answers it exactly, and the assumptions were the right ones.